# find the list of mapping and workflow affecting the particular table in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Can  anyone tell me how to find the list of mapping and the workflow that are using a particular table say `X` either as a source or target table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the source or target in the Designer and select Dependencies. In Object Types select 'Mappings' and 'Workflows' and click OK

Answer (score 4):

Informatica metadata repository stores and maintains information about all the objects in Informatica.So , you have to write an external query to find this :

```
  SELECT   SUBJECT_AREA , MAPPING_NAME
  FROM REP_ALL_MAPPINGS
  where MAPPING_NAME in (
  SELECT MAPPING_NAME FROM REP_SRC_MAPPING
  where SOURCE_NAME ='X')
```

And to find workflows :

```
 select REP_WORKFLOWS.SUBJECT_AREA, REP_WORKFLOWS.WORKFLOW_NAME
 from dbo.REP_WORKFLOWS
 join dbo.REP_WFLOW_RUN
 on REP_WORKFLOWS.WORKFLOW_ID = REP_WFLOW_RUN.WORKFLOW_ID
 where REP_WORKFLOWS.SUBJECT_AREA  in 
 (SELECT   SUBJECT_AREA 
  FROM REP_ALL_MAPPINGS
  where MAPPING_NAME in (SELECT MAPPING_NAME FROM REP_SRC_MAPPING
  where SOURCE_NAME ='X'));
```

Comment: can you tell me where to execute this query?

Comment: @infa : these queries should be run on INFA repository database.A database corresponding to the repository service. Usually developers don't have access to this DB however READ access can be granted if you need to run any of the above queries. Consult informatica admin.

Comment: These are oracle queries. try running them in sql developer after getting read access to the database connections.

Comment: you probably want to remove the dbo. predicate to make it more cross-db compatible